# Hide/Unhide XAML Elements With Button Clicked

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, show-hide, activity-indicator

I've been trying to implement this `ActivityIndicator` when I make a `WebService` request. I've come through a couple of different solutions, and I'm trying the simplest one, as shown here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmX4RD2iyWw

Well, it's not working for me. It seems to me that it is not accepting the new value I want to give the variable. When I set the `IsVisible` variable to **true** by code I can see the spinning circle there, however, when I set the variable to **false** and click the button nothing happens. Also, there should be an "empty" space corresponding to the element which is not there.

Any help would be mostly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

LoginPage.xaml :

```xml
<ContentPage.Content>
  <StackLayout>
    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="activityIndicator" IsVisible="false" IsRunning="True" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30"/>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>

<Button Text="Sign In" Clicked="SignIn" />
```

LoginPage.xaml.cs :

```cs
void SignIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    activityIndicator.IsVisible = true;
    Method();
    activityIndicator.IsVisible = false;
  }
```

Comment: depending on what `Method` is doing it could be blocking the UI thread so that the ActivityIndicator is not able to update until `Method` completes

Comment: You can't do this the way you are attempting. The display won't re-layout until the SignIn method completes. So if you start it "false", you'll never see anything. And there WON'T be blank space reserved for it - read about what IsVisible does. Look for some different working example of an activity indicator. OR is there some small detail in that youtube that you've left out? (I did not watch it.) Any mention of using async/await? Or Task.Run? Sorry, I don't have the details, but basically you need UI thread to not be blocked while "SignIn" runs. ALTERNATIVE solution is to manipulate Opacity.

Comment: @Rafael how is your button outside the content page?
Are you able to hit the debug point in SignIn method?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Overall, I have been able to debug and I could see the visibility flag goinf from true to false while I pressed the buttons

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I think the idea of the method blocking the UI thread is a good guess...  I'll check for these details you mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the comments, I have made some minor changes that got it working. I believe a **await** command was one of the details I was missing.
I'm not sure if this is the best solution though. I'm pretty sure I should be using some kind of flag for this, but I still can't do this.

Below follows two solutions:

**1. By setting the `IsVisible` property to `FALSE`, you manage to hide the `ActivityIndicator`  with no space reserved for the element**

LoginPage.xaml :

```xml
<ContentPage.Content>
  <StackLayout>
    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="activityIndicator" IsVisible="false" IsRunning="True" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30"/>
    <Button Text="Sign In" Clicked="SignIn" />
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

LoginPage.xaml.cs :

```cs
async void SignIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    activityIndicator.IsVisible = true;
    await Task.Delay(500);
    Method();
    activityIndicator.IsVisible = false;
  }
```

**2. By setting the `IsRunning` property to `FALSE`, you manage to hide the `ActivityIndicator` and leave a reserved space for the element**

LoginPage.xaml :

```xml
<ContentPage.Content>
  <StackLayout>
    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="activityIndicator" IsVisible="True" IsRunning="False" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30"/>
    <Button Text="Sign In" Clicked="SignIn" />
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

LoginPage.xaml.cs :

```cs
async void SignIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
    await Task.Delay(500);
    Method();
    activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
  }
```

Comment: When using `await`, the method should be declared `async`:  `async void SignIn(...`

Comment: `hidden: no blank space reserved`. Exactly. That is the defined behavior of `IsVisible`. If you want space reserved; set `Opacity` to either 0 (invisible) or 1 (fully visible). (Remove the `IsVisible` property, or use `IsVisible="true"`)  You can also set `Opacity` to a fraction, to make something partly visible; e.g. `0.5` is half-visible, half-see-through. (If Opacity `0` doesn't reserve space, set a very small number, like `0.001` - this used to be required in some situations on iOS.)

Comment: `<Button Text="Sign In" Clicked="SignIn" />` line should be *inside* the `StackLayout`. Move it to be the next line after `ActivityIndicator` and before the `</StackLayout>` line. Please test this change, and if it works, edit your answer to show the corrected code.

Comment: I think you can just set the property `IsRunning` instead of `IsVisible`

Comment: Sorry, @ToolmakerSteve the button outside the <StackLayout> was a typing mistake! It's not like that in the code... using Opacity instead of IsVisible should work like a charm, would you know if there's a significative performance change? I would guess "removing the element" with IsVisible would perform better than having an invisible spinning wheel there

Comment: Performance wise, its better to use Opacity. Reason: layout doesn't have to be performed every time you show/hide the element. The ActivityIndicator shouldn't be spinning - bind to its `IsRunning` property, Actually, you might not even need to hide it.  If you manually set `IsRunning=False`, does it just show a blank area?  It might do what you want! Then replace `"False"` with a value that you change, instead of doing that to IsVisible.